# Scala argument upper type bounds and overriding

Tags: scala, polymorphism, overriding, upperbound

I am trying to understand and incorporate upper bound types with overriding in my system, but have not been able to achieve it without some ugly code. I have the following 2 traits:

```scala
trait MyId {
  def getType: Int // For simplicity. This is Enum/Object in code.
  def id: Any
}

trait MyTrait {
  protected def supportedType: Int
 
  def doSomething(id: MyId): Unit = {
    if (id.getType == myType) 
      doSomethingInternal(id)
  }
  
  protected def doSomethingInternal(id: _ <: MyId): Unit
}
```

and I want to create subtypes as:

```scala
class X(x: Long) extends MyId {
  override def getType: Int = 1
  override def id: Long = x
}

class Y(y: String) extends MyId {
  override def getType: Int = 2
  override def id: String = y
}

class A extends MyTrait {
  override protected def supportedType: Int = 1

  override protected def doSomethingInternal(id: X): Unit {...}
}

class B extends MyTrait {
  override protected def supportedType: Int = 2

  override protected def doSomethingInternal(id: Y): Unit {...}
}
```

However, this does not work. The workaround I have been using is to use `asInstanceOf[]`:

```scala
class A extends MyTrait {
  override protected def supportedType: Int = 1

  override protected def doSomethingInternal(id: MyId): Unit {
    val id2 = id.asInstanceOf[X]
  }
}

class B extends MyTrait {
  override protected def supportedType: Int = 2

  override protected def doSomethingInternal(id: MyId): Unit {
    val id2 = id.asInstanceOf[Y]
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can get rid of the `asInstanceOf[]`?

#### EDIT

Further more, I have the following processor which requires calling the correct `MyTrait` subclass based on the given `MyId.getType`:

```scala
def process(ids: Seq[MyId], processors: Map[Int, MyTrait]): Unit = {
  ids.foreach{ id =>
    processors.get(id.getType).doSomething(id)
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

- `getType` is `Int` for simplicity here. This is actually an enum/object in my code.
- Renamed `getSomething` to `doSomething` for more clarity.

Comment: I'll start from afar: why is `type` an `Int`???

Comment: Why using a generic parameter does not work for you?

Comment: I have added the EDIT to elaborate more on why.

Comment: @Dima In my actual code, the type is an enum/Object. I just used an Int here to keep it more readable

Comment: @Kyuubi does something like this does what you want? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/vgSuSHzhTPy9T5vt2DMvvg/11

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question if there's a specific need for the indirection between `getSomething` and `getSomethingInternal` other than the `getType` consistency check, but since it looks like the goal is just to prevent calling `getSomething` with the wrong id type, it seems to me it'd be simpler to define MyTrait with a type parameter for the expected id:

```scala
trait MyTrait[T] {
  def getSomething(id: T): Unit
}
class A extends MyTrait[Long] {
  def getSomething(id: Long): Unit = { println(s"long id: $id") }
}
class B extends MyTrait[String] {
  def getSomething(id: String): Unit = { println(s"string id: $id") }
}
```

Then things look like this:

```scala
val a = A()
val b = B()

a.getSomething(123)
// prints "long id: 123"
b.getSomething("abc")
// prints "string id: abc"

a.getSomething("bad") // <--- doesn't compile
b.getSomething(123) // <--- doesn't compile
```

Comment: Thanks. This is reasonable, however, I should update my question to show the situation where this did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what it is exactly that you are trying to do, but, perhaps, something like this will work. The key is to use `Type` for a type, and not attempt to encode it as an `Int` ... and *then* convert to a type.

```
trait MyId[Type] {
  def id: Type
}

trait MyTrait[T] {
  def getSomething(id: MyId[T]): Unit = 
      getSomethingInternal(id.id)
  
  
  protected def getSomethingInternal(id: T): Unit
}
```

Again, this was largely a shot in the dark, because I have no idea why your types are number or why your `gets` return Unit ... among other things.

**Update**
Well, ok, if your type is an "enum", you wanna make your `MyId` a sealed trait:

```
   sealed trait MyId[T] {
      def id: T 
   }
   case class X(id: Long) extends MyId[Long]
   case class Y(id: String) extends MyId[String]
```

But now you want to process your ids uniformely. If the list of processors is static, just do `match`:

```
    def process(ids: Seq[MyId[_]]) = ids.map { 
       case x: X => processX(х)
       case y: Y => processY(y)
    }
```

And if it isn't? Well .. in that case, I'd start with another upda
te to your question, explaining why you need it, and how you generate that dynamic list.

Comment: Thanks, I just elaborated on the question on why I strayed away from this. But maybe i did not do it correctly.

Comment: Added edits to the question for more clarity.